# Where is /usr/local/lib on online server

Tags: php, linux, server

I have a server hosted on 000webhost.com

In the file manager there is a `public_html` folder where I store my website files, but no `\usr` folder.

Generally I could just access this file through the command line or terminal but this is not the case on this server. Unless there are command line tools that I simply couldnt find (I know it is a linux server);

I ran `phpinfo()` and the configuration file path was in `usr/local/lib` but I have no idea how to access that.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need to do in `/usr/local/lib`? 000webhost is a very minimalist shared hosting service if I recall, and provides no access to the system beyond your user space and public_html -- no shell access.  Whatever you are trying to achieve may have alternatives.

Comment: Are you trying to modify php.ini?  The host quite possibly provides no way to do that, other than to use [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) calls in your PHP code at runtime. You would need to consult their support documentation.

Comment: I get the fatal error `call to undefined function msql_connect()` and apparently editing the `php.ini` file can fix this. When I run `phpinfo()` I see that mysql has no active links

Comment: Is the error literally `msql_connect()` or is it actually `mysql_connect()`? Because if the former, you have a typo in your code. Again, consult the host's docs to find out what they support for MySQL.

Comment: Sorry it was actually `mysqli()` that caused the error. `mysql_connect()` seemed to be fine

Comment: But still, `phpinfo()` says all mysql have inactive links, is this ok??

Comment: No active links simply means you currently have no script running with an active connection to the MySQL server. That number would increase if you had one or more concurrent users on your website loading pages.

Comment: In the phpinfo() output, you need to verify that the mysqli extension is present - it will be listed separately from the mysql extension. Again, 000webhost is barebones and may not even support mysqli -- I don't know. That's a question for their support people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php look at the section on connecting to MySql. Your solution is likely there.

Here is a synopsis:

If you cannot connect to MySQL server, there could be some causes:

**- Incorrect MySQL hostname.**
 
Never use 'localhost' as your MySQL hostname! You can find your MySQL hostname by logging on to members area, entering control panel and clicking on MySQL icon.

**- Incorrect MySQL username / password or database name.**
 
You can find / setup MySQL username and database by clicking on MySQL icon from control panel. And you can change MySQL password by clicking on phpMyAdmin icon.

**- Database failed to setup.**
 
In a very rare cases MySQL database can fail to setup. To confirm this, please try to enter phpMyAdmin for any database. If you see database there, that means it setup was successful. And if you get access denied error by trying to enter phpMyAdmin, please delete the database and setup the same MySQL database again.

Please note that always you must give about 1 minute for any changes to apply on server.

If you still unable to connect to MySQL you check if it is server or your script problem in this way: if you can enter phpMyAdmin and see you database there, that means everything is working fine on our side. It's a problem with your PHP script.